# Manually logging in with form based authentication

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication

I have setup form based authentication within my application, but I also want to allow users to login manually, without necessarily hitting a protected resource. In order to do that, would I have to do the work of manually handling the checking of the username and password against the database and set the user?

Comment: If you are using spring framework, Spring Security is what you are looking for. Refer to http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/

Comment: Well, when I originally got the HTTP Status 400 - Invalid direct reference to form login page error, I thought it was because I was directly accessing the jsp that I designated as the login page, so I tried to copy the page and use that one , but that didn't work, and I didn't expect it to. I understand that with form based authentication, the server takes you to the protected resource once you are authenticated and authorized, but I can't quite figure out what to do to 'manually' implement a login. I'm using Hibernate as my JPA implementation, but no real frameworks to speak of.